# How To Limit A Regular Expression Match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working on a project for a clinic which runs OCR on some lab documents then parses the data and automates its entry into their lab system. The raw data is semi-structured enough that I can put it through a series of steps to extract the data I need in the order that I need. I'm starting to hit a wall from staring at it too long and would appreciate another set of eyes on it.

The process works like this:

- first pass over the raw text and extract [**ICD10 CODES**](https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Quality-Initiatives-Patient-Assessment-Instruments/QualityMeasures/ICD-10-and-Quality-Measures) using RegularExpressions which match the standard specification and boundaries that exist specifically to the lab document including potential artifacts from the OCR read.
- second pass that extract **TEST CODES**, which are unfortunately far more variable in terms of character composition. Note that I also have to force boundaries due to the way the document is formatted, the composition of the text, and due to OCR artifacts.
- After these passes I have the data organized in a list which I reorganize and group a certain way. That all works fine.

The regex I am using to extract **TEST CODES** follows:

`(?<=•\s*|\.\s*|\s*)(?<ORDER>[A-Z0-9]{3,9})(?=\s*\||\sJ\s|\sj\s|\sI\s|\s\[\s|\s\]\s)`

Two examples of actual data are below. In the first one I am matching all the test codes (the 4 digit numbers at the start of the line) in addition to matching 3 character groups at the end (GFR,A1C).

The second image looks ideal, with only the test codes being matched.

**How can I not match the three character groups when my test code might indeed be three characters (of upper alpha and digit)?**

[image]
[image]

Three examples of Raw text

```
Adult health examination | ICD-10: ZOO.OO: Encounter for general adult medical examination without abnormal findings; Z13.6:
Encounter for screening for cardiovascular disorders;
• CBCWD | CBC w / differential | BILL: Third Party
• LIPID | lipid panel | BILL: Third Party
• THYCSCD J thyroid cascade profile | BILL: Third Party
• GLYHB | glycated hemoglobin | BILL: Third Party
• CMP | comprehensive metabolic panel | BILL: Third Party
Vitamin D deficiency | ICD - 10: E55.9: Vitamin D deficiency, unspecified
• VITD | vitamin D, 25 - hydroxy | BILL: Third Party

Feces contents abnormal | ICD-10: R19.5: Other fecal abnormalities
CXSTO1 | stool culture complete | BILL: Patient
WBCST | WBC stool | BILL: Patient
IFOBT | occult blood fecal(immunochemical) | BILL: Patient
8623 | ova and parasite exam | BILL: Patient

Fatigue | ICD-10: R53.83: Other fatigue
2834 | TSH reflex to free T4 | BILL: Third Party
1000 | CBC w/auto diff | BILL: Third Party
9180 | comprehensive metabolic panel + E-GFR | BILL: Third Party
4937 | testosterone, free/total with shbg | BILL: Third Party
2708 | hemoglobin A1C | BILL: Third Party
```

Thanks for reading

**Additional wrinkle**

Sometimes data comes across with no newlines depending on the document scanned. Is it possible to match the test codes without matching additional character groups that might apply.

Example:

`Human immunodeficiency virus infection [ ICD-10: B2O.1: Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] disease . 4141 | HIV-1 quant, PCR | BILL: Third Party • 4875 [ cd4 (T4) enumeration j BILL: Third Party • 4474 [ HIV-1 integrase inhibitor resist | BILL: Third Party • 4806 j HIV-1 genotype RT-PCR/sequencing | BILL: Third Party Tuberculosis screening | ICD-10: Z11.1: Encounter for screening for respiratory tuberculosis AC1 • 2515 | T-spot TB test | BILL: Third Party`

Comment: Which language/regex engine? Can you also post the text in plaintext (and not only as an image) so that it's easy for us to test?

Comment: Is the stuff you want to match always between the beginning of the line and the first `|`? If so, then it's trivial. If not, please describe more constraints on where these sequences might show up and which should be rejected. Only take the first group per line? Also, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @ctwheels its C# and raw text added

Comment: @ggorlen yes, only at the beginning of the line. thanks

Comment: @Integration you can anchor it: `(?<=^[.•]?\s*)[A-Z0-9]{3,9}`

Comment: For `THYCSCD J thyroid cascade profile`, do you want to match `THYCSCD` or not? More explicitly, I'm asking if a `\s|` needs to be after the thing you want to match in the first segment or not.

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59161395/2191572). I believe it does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the start of line anchor `^` to ensure you're only getting the first element. With this regex, you'll need to ensure you include [`RegexOptions.Multiline`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b.%e2%80%a2%5d%3f%5cs*%29%5bA-Z0-9%5d%7b3%2c9%7d%5cb&i=Adult+health+examination+%7c+ICD-10%3a+ZOO.OO%3a+Encounter+for+general+adult+medical+examination+without+abnormal+findings%3b+Z13.6%3a%0d%0aEncounter+for+screening+for+cardiovascular+disorders%3b%0d%0a%e2%80%a2+CBCWD+%7c+CBC+w+%2f+differential+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a%e2%80%a2+LIPID+%7c+lipid+panel+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a%e2%80%a2+THYCSCD+J+thyroid+cascade+profile+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a%e2%80%a2+GLYHB+%7c+glycated+hemoglobin+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a%e2%80%a2+CMP+%7c+comprehensive+metabolic+panel+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0aVitamin+D+deficiency+%7c+ICD+-+10%3a+E55.9%3a+Vitamin+D+deficiency%2c+unspecified%0d%0a%e2%80%a2+VITD+%7c+vitamin+D%2c+25+-+hydroxy+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a%0d%0aFeces+contents+abnormal+%7c+ICD-10%3a+R19.5%3a+Other+fecal+abnormalities%0d%0aCXSTO1+%7c+stool+culture+complete+%7c+BILL%3a+Patient%0d%0aWBCST+%7c+WBC+stool+%7c+BILL%3a+Patient%0d%0aIFOBT+%7c+occult+blood+fecal%28immunochemical%29+%7c+BILL%3a+Patient%0d%0a8623+%7c+ova+and+parasite+exam+%7c+BILL%3a+Patient%0d%0a%0d%0aFatigue+%7c+ICD-10%3a+R53.83%3a+Other+fatigue%0d%0a2834+%7c+TSH+reflex+to+free+T4+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a1000+%7c+CBC+w%2fauto+diff+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a9180+%7c+comprehensive+metabolic+panel+%2b+E-GFR+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a4937+%7c+testosterone%2c+free%2ftotal+with+shbg+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party%0d%0a2708+%7c+hemoglobin+A1C+%7c+BILL%3a+Third+Party&o=m) in your call.

[See regex in use here][2]

```
(?<=^[.•]?\s*)[A-Z0-9]{3,9}\b
```

How it works:

- `(?<=^[.•]?\s*)` positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches the following

  - `^` assert position at the start of the line
  - `[.•]?` optionally match any character in the set `.•`
  - `\s*` match any number of whitespace characters
- `[A-Z0-9]{3,9}` match any uppercase ASCII letter or digit between 3 and 9 times
- `\b` assert position as a word boundary

The beauty about the above regex is that `^[.•]?\s*` can match just the starting position of the line since the rest `[.•]?\s*` is all optional

Comment: This seems to work well. Thank you for the explanation of whats going on. I understand it better now. +1 / answered

Comment: I added additional information to the end of the question. I should have included it specifically in the original question. I apologize for that and would appreciate any thoughts. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to anchor your regex and make use of the regularly occurring patterns such as the pipe `|` char:

```
^[\W\s]*(?<ORDER>[A-Z0-9]{3,9})\s+.*?\|
```

Your desired data will be in the named capture group `order` or `$1` if you choose not to name it.

https://regex101.com/r/RNNKEm/1

Comment: It's not matching `THYCSCD`. However, I'd add that he needs to pick the second group to get the order, as the whole regex matches the surrounding characters as well (the first group is the same as the whole matched string).

Comment: @Andrew I assumed OP knows what they were doing with `?<ORDER>` but I've added that detail anyways.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `[^|]*` is faster than `.*?` since it doesn't backtrack

Comment: @ctwheels I recommend testing that suggestion on my regex101 link. Hint: it captures newlines

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I edited my comment, but must've been after you copied it; typo I put `/` instead of `|`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it, don't forget to turn on MULTILINE option:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?:^[•\s\.]*)(?<ORDER>[A-Z0-9]{3,9})", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: This regex would match `WBCSTFJJF` from `WBCSTFJJFJFK | WBC stool | BILL: Patient` which is presumably unwanted behavior because the whole string is not a valid test code.

Comment: Similar example was not provided in the source data, nor said it is unwanted. It is just your presumption.